# Downloading pdf files using mechanize and urllib

Tags: python, eclipse, web-crawler, mechanize, urllib

I am new to Python, and my current task is to write a web crawler that looks for PDF files in certain webpages and downloads them. Here's my current approach (just for 1 sample url):

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import sys

mech = mechanize.Browser()
mech.set_handle_robots(False)

url = "http://www.xyz.com"

try:
    mech.open(url, timeout = 30.0)
except HTTPError, e:
    sys.exit("%d: %s" % (e.code, e.msg))

links = mech.links()

for l in links:
    #Some are relative links
    path = str(l.base_url[:-1])+str(l.url)
    if path.find(".pdf") > 0:
       urllib.urlretrieve(path)
```

The program runs without any errors, but I am not seeing the pdf being saved anywhere. I am able to access the pdf and save it through my browser. Any ideas what's going on? I am using pydev (eclipse based) as my development environment, if that makes any difference.

Another question is if I want give the pdf a specific name while saving it, how can I do that? Is this approach correct? Do I have to create a file with 'filename' before I can save the PDF?

```
urllib.urlretrieve(path, filename)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) says this about the `urlretrieve` function:

> The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy
>   to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name).

The function's return value has the location of the file:

> Return a tuple (filename, headers) where filename is the local file
>   name under which the object can be found, and headers is whatever the
>   info() method of the object returned by urlopen() returned (for a
>   remote object, possibly cached).

So, change this line:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(path)
```

to this:

```
(filename, headers) = urllib.urlretrieve(path)
```

and the path in `filename` will have the location. Optionally, pass in the `filename` argument to urlretrieve to specify the location yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used mechanize, but from the documentation for urllib at http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html:

> urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])
>
> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if
>   necessary. If the URL points to a local file, or a valid cached copy
>   of the object exists, the object is not copied. Return a tuple
>   (filename, headers) where filename is the local file name under which
>   the object can be found, and headers is whatever the info() method of
>   the object returned by urlopen() returned (for a remote object,
>   possibly cached). Exceptions are the same as for urlopen().

As you can see the urlretrieve function saves to a temporary file if you don't specify one.  So try specifying the filename as you suggested in your second piece of code.  Otherwise you could call urlretrieve like this:

```
    saved_filename,headers = urllib.urlretrieve(path)
```

and then use saved_filename later on.