# Download .pdf files from a webiste using python

Tags: python, scripting

i am trying to download all the pdfs from the webiste provided and i am using the following code:

```
import mechanize
from time import sleep
br = mechanize.Browser()


br.open('http://www.nerc.com/comm/CCC/Pages/AgendasHighlightsandMinutes-.aspx')

f=open("source.html","w")
f.write(br.response().read()) 

filetypes=[".pdf"] 
myfiles=[]
for l in br.links(): 
    for t in filetypes:
        if t in str(l): 
            myfiles.append(l)


def downloadlink(l):
    f=open(l.text,"w") 
    br.click_link(l)
    f.write(br.response().read())
    print l.text," has been downloaded"


for l in myfiles:
    sleep(1) 
    downloadlink(l)
```

keep on getting the following error and can't figure out the problem why.

```
legal and privacy  has been downloaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downloads-pdfs.py", line 29, in <module>
    downloadlink(l)
  File "downloads-pdfs.py", line 21, in downloadlink
    f=open(l.text,"w")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/trademark policy'
```

Comment: Start by showing the error, and perhaps showing where you've researched to try to resolve the error.

Comment: It's rather unhelpful to say that you're getting errors, then not say what the errors are. Please don't make it difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Also, it is bad practice to open a file and not close it. Using `with open()` is your friend, and will close files for you.

Comment: Why not print out as much as possible information – such as the linked URL – to make debugging this just a bit easier?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you encounter arises because you use the link URL as a filename. The character '/' is not valid in a filename. Try to modify your `downloadlink` function to something like this:

```
def downloadlink(l):
    filename = l.text.split('/')[-1]
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        br.click_link(l)
        f.write(br.response().read())
    print l.text," has been downloaded"
```

Comment: tried the above but still the code isn't downloading the PDFs.

Comment: yes, you have to use the method described in this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931364/downloading-pdf-files-using-mechanize-and-urllib)